# Approximating the hessian using gradient

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, taylor-expansion, approximation, hessian-matrix

Suppose I have

$$
e(x) = \left(y - f(x) \right)^2,
$$

where $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Let's fix $x_0$ and expand $f$ in $x_0$, this yields

$$
e(x) = (y - f(x_0))^2 - 2(y - f(x_0))((\nabla f)(x_0)\Delta x_0 + \Delta x_0^T H(x_0) \Delta x_0) + ((\nabla f)(x_0)\Delta x_0 + \Delta x_0^T H(x_0) \Delta x_0)^2,
$$

The term
$$((\nabla f)(x_0)\Delta x_0 + \Delta x_0^T H(x_0) \Delta x_0)^2 \approx \left( (\nabla f)(x_0)\Delta x_0\right)^2 = \Delta x_0^T [(\nabla f)(x_0)(\nabla f)(x_0)^T ] \Delta x_0 ,$$ while
$$
(y - f(x_0))((\nabla f)(x_0)\Delta x_0 + \Delta x_0^T H(x_0) \Delta x_0) = (y - f(x_0))(\nabla f)(x_0)\Delta x_0 + (y - f(x_0)) \Delta x_0^T H(x_0) \Delta x_0.
$$

Therefore we can conclude that

$$
e(x) \approx (y - f(x_0))^2 - (y - f(x_0))(\nabla f)(x_0)\Delta x_0 - (y - f(x_0)) \Delta x_0^T H(x_0) \Delta x_0 + \Delta x_0^T [(\nabla f)(x_0)(\nabla f)(x_0)^T ] \Delta x_0 = (y - f(x_0))^2 - (y - f(x_0))(\nabla f)(x_0)\Delta x_0 -  \Delta x_0^T [(y - f(x_0)) H(x_0) + (\nabla f)(x_0)(\nabla f)(x_0)^T ] \Delta x_0
$$

Which means that the hessian matrix of $e(x)$ is given by
$$
H_e(x_0) = H(x_0) + (\nabla f)(x_0)(\nabla f)(x_0)^T,
$$

however in standard minimization algorithms I've seen many times using $$H_e(x_0) \approx (\nabla f)(x_0)(\nabla f)(x_0)^T,$$

why is the hessian of $f$ entirely rejected?

Comment: I don't follow your calculations. Calculating the Hessian of $e$ retrieves
$$H_e(x_0)= 2H_f(x_0)\,(f(x_0)-y)+2(\nabla f(x_0))\cdot (\nabla f(x_0))^T.$$ Here I assume that $y$ is not one of the variables with respect to which you take the Hessian, but a fixed number towards which you want to optimise.

Comment: If my calculation are wrong can you please either: 1) point out where you think I'm missing something (so I can correct); or 2) post the complete calculation? $y$ is not a variable, correct.

Comment: $$\partial_i\partial_j (f - y)^2 = \partial_i 2(f-y) \partial_j f  = 2\partial_if\partial_j f+ 2(f-y)\partial_i\partial_j f$$

Comment: My calculations are wrong... you're right... uff...

Comment: Do you have a reference for "standard minimization algorithms"? Are they possibly for linear optimization?

Comment: Any LSE algorithm would involve such stuff (linear and non linear).